# How does Discord embed YouTube-Playable Videos?

Tags: html, youtube, discord

Recently I've been wondering how [Discord](https://discord.com) has been able to embed a Youtube video,

In the link for ex: [image][Example](https://prntscr.com/uso836.png)

The reason I'm wondering is because I am currently developing a website that would love to have this potential feature when posting links such as https://example.com/le-BoDs-Yt8 which then discord would output a similar style of embed like the YouTube one.

Any ideas on how this is done?

Comment: I think they copy the embed code.

Comment: Oh? they have that feature, honestly forgot about that being a thing on Youtube, thanks for the idea; I'll take a look into that, much appreicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks [@Spectric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14251221/spectric) this is most certainly the answer-ish except it's in a meta tag using [OpenGraph](https://ogp.me/), except one issue it doesn't allow you to play your own custom files example: .mp4's.

Example of OPG:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ur3-A7ovGUk">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ur3-A7ovGUk/maxresdefault.jpg">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ur3-A7ovGUk">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="720">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280">
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other">
```

```html
<iframe width="1004" height="753" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cIwTYL1fwJk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

They most definitely retrieve the embed code (via right-clicking the video and select 'Copy embed code'), and add it to the message, along with the title + subtitle.

For example:

```
<iframe width="1004" height="753" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cIwTYL1fwJk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

```html
<iframe width="1004" height="753" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cIwTYL1fwJk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't that is what I'm looking for as I think the way its done is via meta tagging, but still unsure at the moment.